# High CPU load when loading images in media library

Tags: media-library, server-load

I notice it uses high cpu when I load images from my media library. I have about over 1 million images uploaded and they are organized into folders by Post ID. Any tips to reducing CPU?

Comment: which cpu, the client machine or the server?, and what is exactly high. please give as much details as possible.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any especially CPU when loading an image-- when saving the image, possibly, but not when loading it--, unless maybe the images are enormous, there are a lot of them, or you are loading via some script that does some processing at load time-- `my-image-loader.php`, or `my-image-loader.js`, something like that. Any of that sound familiar?

Answer (score 2):

When you upload an image, WordPress generates multiple images for each image size, e.g. medium, thumbnail, large etc

If you have a lot of custom image sizes you could cut down, but uploading 1 million images is going to take a lot of cpu, even without the resizing.

On top of that, **each upload generates an attachment post, meaning your site effectively has at least 1 million posts to handle**. This slows down listings considerably. Your CPU will be busy handling the queries for those posts in mysql, and grabbing each.

Given the sheer quantity, the only real tip I can give you that will have any noticeable impact, is to start deleting images.

Comment: someone downvoted me, why? Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: that'd be me. I downvote your comment by mistake when I was using my left hand with mouse. Sorry about this.

Comment: Ah no worries ^_^